# Как быстро скопировать большое кол-во маленьких файлов из 1 места в другое

Tags: windows, администрирование, резервное-копирование

Допустим, имеется большое кол-во маленьких файлов.

Как мне их быстро скопировать из одного места в другое?

Даст ли какую-либо выгоду параллелизм?

Comment: Узким местом наверняка будет сам диск, так что много потоков выгоды не дадут.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов если SSD, то, по идее, должно дать.

Comment: @rjhdby Хм... Думаю от реализации сильно зависеть будет. Особенно если запись начнет приходится на один кристалл.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов более того, если диск шпиндельный, то много потоков наоборот могут довольно сильно затормозить процесс

Comment: @rjhdby я думал об этом, но реальные замеры производить лениво :-)

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если у вас шпиндельный накопитель, то многопоточность может наоборот замедлить процесс, так как диск будет постоянно позиционировать головку обслуживая потоки по очереди.

За SSD не скажу, но обывательская логика подсказывает два варианта:
1) Выгода будет.
2) Выгоды не будет, но и просадки тоже.

Вариант с локальной архивацией(без сжатия например) и последующим переносом архива не рассматривали?